# DBCC CHECKIDENT can't find the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dbcc

I have table that has an id which both an identity AND primary key of a table.  When run this

```
Use devdb
Select * from tablename order by did desc
```

works and I see the data.  When I run the following, I see the table in list

```
Use devdb
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables order by TABLE_NAME
```

But when I run this:

```
Use devdb;
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('<TableName>.<ColumnName>', RESEED, 100000);
```

I get

```
Msg 2501, Level 16, State 45, Line 2
Cannot find a table or object with the name "<tablename>.<columnname>". Check the system      catalog.
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName.ColumnName', RESEED, 100000);`

Comment: Because you didn't specify the right column name?

Comment: Oh I see...@Linger noticed the <> in there.

Comment: The format that I have it is `TableName.ColumnName`.  There are no brackets in the actual code.

Comment: Don't specify the column. See the [MSDN definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057(v=sql.105).aspx): `DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name[, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ] } } ] )`

Comment: Thanks Mike and @Vulcronos. That did it.  Since I followed your comment (mike was faster), if you put answer I will accept it.  Thanks all. You guys are great!

Comment: Folks, the documentation is incorrect for sql server 2008.  See the examples a-c at this link below.  Someone else also commented about the error:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) for CHECKIDENT.  It only takes in a table name because tables are restricted to only a single identity column so there is no need to give a column name.  Just run:

```
Use devdb;
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('<TableName>', RESEED, 100000);
```

Comment: The documentation is wrong.  Please see examples a-c at the bottom of the page for sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

If your schema is not default ('dbo.TableName'), the command will fail.
Make sure your use the correct ('schemaName.tableName') context